# Redirect two steps back in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Using Symfony 4, I have a route to edit an entity that redirects the user to another route after submission like so:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        //....

        $em->persist($thisEntity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('this_entity_index');
    }
```

On the `index page` of the entity that is rendered through the route `this_entity_index`  I display buttons to edit an entity, so this redirect makes sense. However, I have a different `show page` (rendered through a `show_route`) for this entity, which also contains an edit button that routes to the edit-route. After editing, the user would again be redirected to the `index page` of the entity. What I would like to happen in that case, is to have to user redirected to the `show page` in that case, so essentially, I need to send the user two steps back. 
If I use:

```
return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
```

The user simply gets send back to the edit form (one step back). Perhaps there is a simply solution to send the user back two steps? This way I could send the user back to the `index page`, `show page` or any other page the user came from. Do I have to work with the session of the user? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: is it always the index page of entity you want to redirect abck to?

Comment: No, the exact opposite. It currently is redirecting to the index route (i will rename this is my question).

Comment: lemme rephrase - will the user, when clicking the back button always go to the `show page` page?

Comment: No, this depends where the user started. User can go back to `show page` or to `index page` (and in the future more pages).

Comment: Unless you'rre keeping a tracking of visited pages, you won't be able to do what you need.

Comment: I do this using the session.  Forget about the "two step back".  Just store the route name you want to return to in the session and then pull it when you redirect.

Comment: @Cerad, I take it there is no built in solution? Considering yours, how have you implemented this? I have been reading about sessions and it seems i need to set the name in every controller with `$session->set()`, is that correct? Currently I only use sessions for flash messages, so I am not too familiar. I'd be happy with some pointers.

Comment: Something like $request->getSession()->set('entity_edit_redirect_route_name',$request->attributes->get('_route')); will set a session variable to the current route.  You can use has and get for retrieving it.  All in the docs.  There are several approaches to implementing this depending on exactly what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hidden input added in form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="{{app.request.headers.get('referer')}}"/>
```

and

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    //....

    $em->persist($thisEntity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($request->request->get('referer'));
}
```

Comment: Ha, original solution, I like it. There were some small mistakes in the code I edited, because the redirect with your code is not to a route, but to a URL and there was a typo. Thx for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I came up with more complex solution which can be used in form as classes approach. I just created a redirect field type, which can handle some logic for me and it's easy to put in every form. The logic behind is the same as in Deniz Aktürk solution.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FieldRedirectType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $parentName = $form->getParent()->getName();

            $currentRequest = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
            $post = $currentRequest->request->get($parentName);

            $redirectUrl = isset($post[$form->getName()]) ? $post[$form->getName()] : '';
            $referer = $currentRequest->headers->get('referer');
            if (empty($redirectUrl) && ! empty($referer)) {
                $redirectUrl = $referer;
            } else if ($redirectUrl == $referer) {
                $redirectUrl = '';
            }

            $config = $form->getParent()->get($form->getName())->getConfig();
            $options = $config->getOptions();

            $form->getParent()->add($form->getName(), HiddenType::class, array_replace($options, [
                'data' => $redirectUrl,
            ]))
            ;
        });
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return HiddenType::class;
    }
}
```

First of all I "extends" `HiddenType` field making it a base field type.
Then I use [PRE_SET_DATA](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#pre-populating-the-form-formevents-pre-set-data-and-formevents-post-set-data) event to set proper data to my hidden field based on earlier request or headers. I need to get data from my previous request in case if there are validation errors. Because after submitting such form my referrer will change and will be pointing to my edit/add form page. This is why at first time I need to save my referrer into hidden field and after that rely on posted data, not referrer header directly.
Inside that event you can't retrieve data from *redirect* field as the form data has not already been set. This is why I need to get data directly from post request.
SF creates posts array by adding main form type key to the response. So for the *user* form type the final array is like that:

```
array:1 [
  "user" => array:9 [
    "email" => "email"
    "first_name" => "name"
    "last_name" => "lastname"
    "_redirectUrl" => "where_to_redirect_back"
  ]
]
```

The *user* key you can retrieve by `$parentName = $form->getParent()->getName();`
Now based on posted `$redirectUrl` and referers you can determine which value is the correct one.

Then you have to set the proper value to the field, but again you can't use `setData()` method because of event's cycle. 
This is why we have to get all initial options of field set in parent form. Then inject new value using [data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html#data) option to the field. Finally add field to the parent form, which is treated by SF as replacing the field if name already exists.

Finally you can just use that field as follows:

```php
$form->add('_redirectUrl', FieldRedirectType::class); // inside controller or in other form type class

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $redirectUrl = $form->get('_redirectUrl')->getData();
    if (empty($redirectUrl)) { // in case of empty value, redirect to some default place
        return $this->redirectToRoute('default_basic_route');
    }
    return $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
}
```

It works also as a 2 (n) steps back redirection if you have got more then one form to fill and finally you want that user to be redirected to the first page from which he came from. You have to pass to *redirectField* a value from previous *redirectField*. Firstly added *redirectField* should have got no initial value, so it can set it from referer header.